# How to disable sort in DataGridView?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, sorting, datagridview

How can I disable sort in `DataGridView`? I need to disable the header `DataGridView` sorting.

Comment: You may want to know that it is disabled by default. But maybe you mean how to toggle it (disable after being enabled).

Comment: Use DGV's event ColumnAdded, or override OnColumnAdded function. [Source](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/32c8d256-3fe7-4cf3-84dc-b1322b781c73/how-to-disable-the-column-header-sorting-in-datagridview?forum=Vsexpressinstall)

Comment: @Gold 9 years and still mulling this one over?

Answer (score 108):

```
foreach (DataGridViewColumn column in dataGridView.Columns)
{
    column.SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable;
}
```

Answer (score 24):

Use LINQ:

```
Datagridview1.Columns.Cast<DataGridViewColumn>().ToList().ForEach(f => f.SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable);
```

Answer (score 23):

If you want statically make columns not sortable. You can do this way

1. Open the EditColumns window of the DataGridView control.
2. Select the column you want to make not sortable on the left side pane.
3. In the right side properties pane, select the Sort Mode property and select "Not Sortable" in that.

Comment: Ah, that fixed it. You might want to edit that answer to get the enumeration working right, though ;)

Comment: Or calling CanUserSort = "False" (VS15)

Answer (score 7):

It's very simple:

```
foreach (DataGridViewColumn dgvc in dataGridView1.Columns)
{
    dgvc.SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable;
}
```

Comment: How does this answer differ from the one from @hunter that is five years older?

Answer (score 2):

You can disable it in the ColumnAdded event:

```
private void dataGridView1_ColumnAdded(object sender, DataGridViewColumnEventArgs e)
{
    dataGridView1.Columns[e.Column.Index].SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
private void dataGridView1_DataBindingComplete(object sender, DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs e)
{
      for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; i++)
      {
           dataGridView1.Columns[i].SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable;
      }
}
```

Comment: While this may answer the question, it's always best to include a description/references wherever possible.

Answer (score 0):

If you can extend the DataGridView you can override the `Sort` method with am empty one. This disables Sort for the DataGridView entirely.

```
public override void Sort(DataGridViewColumn dataGridViewColumn, ListSortDirection direction)
{
    //base.Sort(dataGridViewColumn, direction);
}
```

Note: You cannot even programmatically sort any column.

Answer (score 0):

For extending control functionality like this, I like to use extension methods so that it can be reused easily.  Here is a starter extensions file that contains an extension to disable sorting on a datagridview.

To use it, just include it in your project and call like this

myDatagridView.DisableSorting()

In my case, I added this line of code in the DataBindingComplete eventhandler of the DataGridView where I wanted sorting disabled

```
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Reflection
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices
Imports System.Windows.Forms

Public Module Extensions

<Extension()>
Public Sub DisableSorting(datagrid As DataGridView)
    For index = 0 To datagrid.Columns.Count - 1
        datagrid.Columns(index).SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable
    Next
End Sub


End Module
```

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a way to disable my already existing `DataGridView` and came across several answers. Oddly enough, the first few results on google were some very old topics. This being the earliest one of them, I decide to put my answer here.

```
private void dgvDetails_ColumnStateChanged(object sender, DataGridViewColumnStateChangedEventArgs e)
{
    e.Column.SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable;
}
```

The description when you click on `ColumStateChanged` in the properties window is:

> "Occurs when a column changes state, such as gaining or loosing focus"

Granted there are many ways to do this but I thought I'd add this one here. Can't say I found it anywhere else but then again I only read the first 5 topics I found.