# DataGridView disabling/enabling sorting based on a condition

Tags: c#, sorting, datagridview, datatable

I've been working on a project where I have a DataTable binded to DataGridView (2 Columns, double type). What I want to do is I want to sort programmatically when user add new row. But the problem is, it needs to be sorted only when user fill all the columns, not just one column.

Even though DataGridViewSortMode is set to NotSortable, when user add new row and fill only one column, it automatically sorts data.

#### UPDATE 1:

```
// This is the Form1_Load event. 
// Basically populates X, Y, then adds them into DataTable, finally binds it to DataGridView.

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Generate X-Y Data
        double[] X = new double[]
        { 50, 200, 400, 1000 };

        double[] Y = new double[]
        { 150, 300, 50, 250};


        // Create DataTable
        DataTable dTable = new DataTable();

        // Define Column Headers
        dTable.Columns.Add("X", typeof(double));
        dTable.Columns.Add("Y", typeof(double));

        // Add Rows to DataTable
        for (int i = 0; i < X.Length; i++)
        {
            dTable.Rows.Add(X[i], Y[i]);

        }

        // Bind DataTable to DataGridView
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dTable;

    }
```

#### dataGridView1_CellEndEdit Event

```
// This is called when user finishes typing. 
// Objective is to determine if all rows are filled. 
// IF: all rows have some value --> Sort; IF not --> Do NOT sort data.

 private void dataGridView1_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {

        if (isNullorEmpty()) // Call a method to see if any row is empty
        {
            dataGridView1.Columns.Cast<DataGridViewColumn>().ToList().
                ForEach(f => f.SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable); // Do not sort because some columns are empty
        }
        else
        {
            dataGridView1.Sort(dataGridView1.Columns[0], ListSortDirection.Ascending); // Sort data since all columns and rows have value
        }
    }
```

---

## SOLVED!

I've just added "return" command when any rows determined as empty, and voila!

**This is edited dataGridView1_CellEndEdit Event**

```
private void dataGridView1_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{

    if (isNullorEmpty()) // Call a method to see if any row is empty
    {
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        dataGridView1.Sort(dataGridView1.Columns[0], ListSortDirection.Ascending); // Sort data since all columns and rows have value
    }
}
```

Comment: I misunderstand your question, I will delete my answer. And [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4502442/how-to-disable-sort-in-datagridview) is same question, I think you have already looked at this.

Comment: Yes, I already looked at that question. Unfortunately, no luck for me.

Comment: Your code should work, I tried and worked. Can you share codes of binding datasource of grid? and if there another grid events used

Comment: I've just updated my post. Please take a look at. Code only works if user finishes typing by pressing arrows on keyboard. If Enter is clicked then it does not work.

Comment: I tried and worked for me, did you run project in debug mode? Are you sure `dataGridView1.Columns.Cast<DataGridViewColumn>().ToList().
                ForEach(f => f.SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable);` executes? I checked cell values like this `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(dataGridView1[0, e.RowIndex].Value.ToString())`

Comment: Yes I am running my project in debug mode. 
It works when you add new row for first time. Then if I add second or third row, it automatically sorts data even though column 2 values are missing